# Limit proof check, show $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of its limit point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

**edit:** as lem has pointed out, the case where x=c is not handled. Could someone suggest an idea?

Prove that if a function $f : A \to \mathbb{R} $ has a limit $l \in \mathbb{R} $ at $c \in L(A)$, then it is bounded in a neighborhood of $c$, i.e there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta) \cap A$, $\|f(x)\| \leq M$

**Note: $L(A)$** signifies the set of limit points in $A$.
And these results use end points in definitions for limits.

My attempt:

Since $f$ has a limit $l \in \mathbb{R}$ at a point $c \in L(A)$, then by definition $\forall \epsilon >0 \space \exists \space \delta \space \text{s.t if} \space x \in A \space \text{and} \space 0 < |x-c| \leq \delta \space \text{it holds that} |f(x)-l| \leq \epsilon$

Then $$l - \epsilon \leq f(x) \leq \epsilon + l$$
if $$c - \delta \leq x \leq \delta + c$$

Thus if $$M = max(l - \epsilon, l+ \epsilon)$$
then when $$x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta) \cap A$$
$$|f(x)| \leq M$$

Is this a sufficient/correct proof?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof checks out except for a minor detail. You should take $M:= \max (|l-\epsilon|,|l+\epsilon|)$ since these quantities could be negative.

You should also say something like "choose $\epsilon = 1$, then by the definition of $f$ having a limit we can find $\delta$ such that...". Don't just leave $\epsilon,\delta$ indeterminate.

Just to show you that there is no reason for you to fill up the page in order for your proof to be correct, here's an even shorter proof than yours:

Suppose $f$ were unbounded on every interval around $c$. Then there is a sequence $x_n \to c$ with $|f(x_n)|\geq n$. Then $|f(x_n)| \to \infty \neq |l|$.

Comment: But in the line above we have
$$ l - \epsilon \leq f(x) \leq l + \epsilon$$

Do i need to add absol]ue values here too?

Comment: That line is correct, but you are trying to say $|f| \leq M$. If $f(x) \in [a,b]$ then $|f| \in [0,\max(|a|,|b|)]$

Comment: AH, I see. thanks @nulluser

I am curious, however. This is indeed a homework question, and the allocated space and marks we have for the question seems to be a lot more than just this few lines of proof. 

Do you think that there could be something I am over looking, or some minor detail missing, or some step I could elaborate further on?

Comment: The ideas in your proof is correct. Don't be fooled into thinking you have to fill up the page. Some students write bigger than others, so instructors often give a ton of space. It also gives you room to make mistakes and think about your ideas without feeling "caged" by the page.

Comment: thanks, i was just scared lol

Answer (score 0):

x∈(c−δ,c+δ)∩A could still contain the point c, but from the definition of a limit 0<|x−c|≤δ so x can't be equal to c. 
so there may be something else missing from this proof.